# How to replace a string based on first and last character

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like this:

```
AR AT_DPI_EUR REL CFO
CL AG_DUT_EUR ORM CFO
GL AX_FRG_EUR TAX USER
AR AT_DFT_EUR CREDIT
```

How to remove only the middle part of the string, so that I can get this output:

```
AR REL CFO
AR ORM CFO
GL TAX USER
AR CREDIT
```

Comment: Is the thing you're trying to remove always the same string?  Always in the same character or word position?  You need to define the problem a bit better.

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: No the middle part will change

Answer (score 5):

Because the middle part is changing you will need to remove the second word. You can do this by splitting the string and rejoining it without that word.

```
x = s.split()
s = " ".join(x[0]+x[2:])
```

Comment: You can use regular expressions, but probably this is the faster and easier way.

Comment: @ThalesMarques that is true but it is not necessary is such a basic problem

Answer (score 1):

if that element has statically second position, you can pop that element with which position it is placed.

```
    lst = ['AR,' ,'AT_DPI_EUR' ,'REL' ,'CFO']
    lst.pop(1)
```

Comment: Maybe you should add the `split()` part, since the start is a plain string.